# How can I edit a post using React hooks? This is my biggest challenge in learning react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have tried everything I can imagine but at the end, the edit function will be doing creating function.

I know editing takes two parts, the fetching initial value and the actual editing it.

Please if someone can make me understand how to Edit an item in react, it will make me very very HAPPY!

What I want to achieve is the ability to click on the edit button, the field gets populated with the current data I wish to edit. When I click on the submit button, it will save the changes and return the edited version. But what is happening instead is that the submit button is creating a new data with the value given for editing.

Please here is my code example of my problem.

```
I passed the initial state from the detail component.

import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {deleteGame} from '../action/gameActions'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import GameForm from './GameForm'

function GameDetails({game, deleteGame}) {
  
  const {_id, title, imageUrl} = game

  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false)

  if(isEditing) {
    return (
      <div>
        <GameForm
        id={_id}
        title={title}
        imageUrl={imageUrl}
        setIsEditing={setIsEditing}
        />
      </div>
    )
  
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="container" >
        <h3>{title}</h3>
         <h4>{imageUrl}</h4>
         <button onClick={()=>deleteGame(_id)}>Delete</button>
         
           <button onClick={()=>setIsEditing(true)}>Edit</button>
        
      </div>
    )
  }
  
}

export default connect(null, {deleteGame})(GameDetails)
```

```
I used Form component for editing and creating data

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {createGame, gameEdit} from '../action/gameActions'


function GameForm({ createGame, gameEdit, setIsEditing, _id, title, imageUrl}) {

  
  const [game_, setGame] = useState({
    id : _id || '',
    title : title || '',
    imageUrl : imageUrl || '',
    errors : ''
  })

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setGame({
      ...game_,
      [e.target.name] : e.target.value
    })
  }

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let error = ''
    const {title, imageUrl, id} = game_
    if(!title || !imageUrl) {
      error = 'Input can\'t be empty'
      setGame({errors: error}) 
      return
    }
    const newGame = {
      
      id,
      title,
      imageUrl 
    }

    if(id){
      gameEdit(_id, newGame)
      setIsEditing(false)
    }
    else {
      createGame(newGame)
    setGame({
      title : '',
      imageUrl : ''
    })
    }
    
  }

  

  return (
    <div className="container">
      {
        game_.errors && <h4>{game_.errors}</h4>
      }
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Title" name="title" value={game_.title} onChange={handleChange} />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Image Url" name="imageUrl" value={game_.imageUrl} onChange={handleChange} />
    <button>{game_.id?(<h4>Edit</h4>):(<h4>Create</h4>)}</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default connect(null, {createGame, gameEdit})(GameForm)
```

```
Redux Action

export const gameEdit = (id, game) => dispatch => {
  const req = {
    method : "DELETE",
    headers : {"Content-Type":"application/json"},
    body : JSON.stringify(game)
  }
 
  fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/game/${id}`, req)
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(data=>dispatch({
     type : GAME_EDIT,
     payload : game
   }))
}
```

```
Redux Reducer

import {GAME_DELETE, GAME_EDIT, GAME_ITEM, GAME_LIST, GAME_CREATE} from '../action/types'

const initialState = {
  games : []
}

export default function(state=initialState, action){
switch (action.type) {
  case GAME_LIST:
    return{
      ...state,
      games : action.payload
    }

  case GAME_EDIT:
    
    return{
      ...state,
      games : state.games.map(game => game._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : game)
    }  

  case GAME_CREATE:
    return{
      ...state,
      games : [action.payload, ...state.games]
    }  

  case GAME_DELETE:
    return {
      ...state,
      games : state.games.filter(game => game._id != action.payload)
    }  
    

  default:
    return state
}
}
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of your source code? Many users here aren't too friendly without showing what you suspect should work

Comment: Thanks Steve, I just did like you advised.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want us to help you with here. 'Edit an item in React' is a very broad idea and without knowing exactly what you're trying to achieve it's going to be difficult for us to make any meaningful suggestions. Which specific part of the code you've posted is not behaving how you expect?

Comment: Great! A few things I noticed you may want to try out to get a better handle on hooks is `useReducer` for your reducer/redux method (you won't need to wrap the export with `connect`), `useCallback` for your event handlers (be sure to include outside dependencies in an array as the 2nd argument) and breaking out your `useState` into individual states rather than one state object (the React docs recommend this for the state hook but its not a deal breaker if implemented correctly across other hooks). This won't exactly fix your issue but should get you on the right path to using hooks.

Comment: You may already reference this but just in case: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html

Comment: Lawrence, thanks for your contribution, I really appreciate. What I want to achieve is the ability to click on the edit button, the field gets populated with the current data I wish to edit. When I click on the submit button, it will save the changes and return the edited version. But what is happen instead is that the submit button is creating a new data with the value given for editing.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I will practice what you just thought.